# using source table from one server to add a destination table to a new server in sql server with same data

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a table on one server and I am wanting to create a destination table on another server that is not linked. This table has over 6 million rows and it would need to be updated daily. How would I perform this in SSIS. I would like to keep audit information as well on this. Need to understand the best way of doing this in SSIS. I have already created the destination table on the destination server inside its database and now I need to get data into it and update it daily through SSIS.

Comment: A Merge Join would be worth looking into. Not sure what performance would be like with 6 million rows. Maybe something like this https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5082/synchronize-table-data-using-a-merge-join-in-ssis.

Comment: @Isaac how would I accomplish this if I only have one source for my data would I just use the one source table then merge it into the destination? Or could I use the one source table and also the new destination table as one of my sources that is currently empty add the merge to the two sources then use that same destination table that I used in second source as the destination table that was currently empty before?

Comment: I have not used this technique myself, but it seems to me that your set up your source table as one of your data sources and you destination table as the other. You use the Merge Join step to detect what has been changed (inserted, updated, or deleted) in the source when compared to the destination. Next a Conditional Split will allow you to determine what to do in the destination to sync it up with the source.

Comment: Another approach would be to copy the entire contents of the source table to a staging stable on the destination server. You would truncate the staging table at the beginning of you SSIS package, reload it with the latest data from the source, and then you the MERGE sql statement to sync the ultimate destination table with the staging table. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1704/using-merge-in-sql-server-to-insert-update-and-delete-at-the-same-time/

Comment: Is there some reason you cannot do this via replication? That would be the way to go.